# Magento2 : Admin dashboard keep showing login form

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, dashboard, admin-login

I have set staging database to local setup.
Frontend is working good.

For backend after login dashboard url is shoiwng
http:// xyz . com / admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/9fea02870e23e77980f350eb2b73889e0bdb04239781c66e533e065dcf19ed98/

with login form. [image]

I have run all commands and not showing any error in log files.
I have also try to create new admin user, new admin user is also not able to see dashboard page, same login form is shoiwng after login form submit.

Comment: Need to run this command: bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to set max_session_size_admin

```
magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 1024000
magento cache:clean config
```

Magento 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link maybe its helpful for you
[Login redirect when trying to login to Commerce Admin](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028606711-Login-redirect-when-trying-to-login-to-Commerce-Admin)

Moreover Check either your Magento Version is compatible with your php version.

Comment: not working.......

Comment: Your's Magento version and php version ?

Comment: M2.4.4, php 8.1

Comment: have you try it on some other browser ? e.g. FireFox, maybe having some cookies issue

Comment: yes, issue with .domain

Comment: when i remove . from domain then dashboard page is loading but when i click to other link it ask again to login.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in the local, while setting up Magento 2.4.4 and that's also in windows system. I have figured out the issue by this way.

> Add extra code in the below file Path:-
> \vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

```
    /**
     * Checks whether path related to the directory
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string|array $directories
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
        //Start Extra Code
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath);   
        //End Extra Code
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

After adding this run deploy command and remove files from var and generated folder.

> php bin/magento s:d:com

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue on magento 2.4.6.
For other test purpose i setted `web/cookie/cookie_domain` to `.example.com`.
Reverted to `example.com` it returns to work correctly.