# Admin Login not working

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-login, magento2.4.4, php8

After upgrading Magento to 2.4.4 with PHP 8.1 and resolving most of the errors. I can't login to the admin panel.

After submitting the credentials it redirects me back to login, while I can see the URL showing `admin/dashboard/key/xxxxxxx` I can see the generated token key but it's not passing.

```
https://example.com/adminpanel/admin/dashboard/index/key/08150d88e801f43e6a3dcc4cb547042ee281e721d7542d3abffae6d5b9c68086/
```

`PHP SODIUM` is installed using PHP 8.1

The question was asked here:
[Admin Login Issue 2.4.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356748/admin-login-issue-2-4-4) and  [Magento2 : Admin dashboard keep showing login form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356608/magento2-admin-dashboard-keep-showing-login-form)

but no resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after upgrading to 2.4.4.
For me, running the following command worked

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000
```

Also try clearing cache from browser and open in incognito